# Title depending on other variable in SAPUI5

Tags: xml, sapui5

Sometimes when I want to show something and hide other thing I just do:
`visible={some_variable}` for example `<Column visible={some_variable}>`. Now I have to deal with `Dialog` title I mean:
I would like to do something depending on other variable - if `variable` is a then `title="{i18n>a}"` and if `variable` is b then `title="{i18n>b}"`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ternary operator works in sapui5 bindings. So in this case, you could do:

```
<Dialog title="{= ${variable} === 'A' ? ${i18n>a} : ${i18n>b} }" />
```

If it gets more complicated, a formatter might be a better solution.